# How to add quotations around numbers in Vim - Regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to add quotation marks around some numbers in my file using regex. To clarify, let me give an example of what I am trying to do.

Something like `myFunction(100)` would be changed to `myFunction("100")`.

I thought `:100,300s/\([0-9]*\)/"\0"` would work but it put quotation marks around spaces as well.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing slash at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working as expected is because `[0-9]*` is matching all strings of zero length, so your substitution is adding two quotes between every two characters. Changing it to `[0-9]+` (to require *at least one* digit) will solve your problem.

As an additional improvement, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`. Also, `\0` is the replacement for the entire matched expression, so your parentheses are unnecessary: `:100,300s/\d+/"\0"` will accomplish what you want. Captured subgroups start at `\1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should slightly modify the regular expression:

```
%s/\(\d\+\)/"\1"
```

In regular expression, first matched group is `\1`, not `\0`. And it looks safer to use `\+` instead of `*`.

Comment: Additionally `%s/\d\+/"&"`